# log4j and NoSQL databases

Tags: log4j, nosql

While looking through the log4j documentation I noticed that a database could be a logging target. A bit more research later it looked like only SQL databases can be targeted. Could NoSql databases be included as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything can be included if you just write an [Appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Appender.html).

One of the databases which lends itself more easily to logging is MongoDB with its capped collection option, see overview [here](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/172254834/mongodb-is-fantastic-for-logging).

An implementation and more in-depth explanations can be found in the Log4mongo project [wiki](http://log4mongo.org/display/PUB/Log4mongo+for+Java)